# Adding values to a dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been having issues with adding values to already existing key values.

Here's my code:

```
mydict = {}

def assemble_dictionary(filename):
   file = open(filename,'r')
   for word in file:
       word = word.strip().lower() #makes the word lower case and strips any unexpected chars
       firstletter = word[0]
       if firstletter in mydict.keys():
           continue
       else:
           mydict[firstletter] = [word]

   print(mydict)

assemble_dictionary('try.txt')
```

The `try.txt` contains a couple of words - `Ability` , `Absolute`, `Butterfly`, `Cloud`. So `Ability` and `Absolute` should be under the same key, however I can't find a function that would enable me to do so. Something similar to

```
mydict[n].append(word)
```

where n would be the line number.

Furthermore is there a way to easily locate the number of value in dictionary?

Current Output =

```
{'a': ['ability'], 'b': ['butterfly'], 'c': ['cloud']}
```

but I want it to be

```
{'a': ['ability','absolute'], 'b': ['butterfly'], 'c': ['cloud']}
```

Comment: can you please share the sample input?

Comment: The input is at the bottom of the code- assemble_dictionary('try.txt') where try.txt contains words Ability , Absolute, Butterfly, Cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 :

you can put append statement when checking key is already exist in dict.

```
mydict = {}

def assemble_dictionary(filename):
   file = open(filename,'r')
   for word in file:
       word = word.strip().lower() #makes the word lower case and strips any unexpected chars
       firstletter = word[0]
       if firstletter in mydict.keys():
           mydict[firstletter].append(word)
       else:
           mydict[firstletter] = [word]

   print(mydict)
```

option 2 : 
you can use dict setDefault to initialize the dict with default value in case key is not present then append the item.

```
mydict = {}

def assemble_dictionary(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
        for word in file:
            word = word.strip().lower() #makes the word lower case and strips any unexpected chars
            firstletter = word[0]
            mydict.setdefault(firstletter,[]).append(word)
    print(mydict)
```

Comment: Thanks, the .append(word) works now. Not sure why it didn't previously as I've tried that before x)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply append your word to the existing key:

```
def assemble_dictionary(filename):
   with open(filename,'r') as f:
       for word in f:
           word = word.strip().lower() #makes the word lower case and strips any unexpected chars
           firstletter = word[0]
           if firstletter in mydict.keys():
               mydict[firstletter].append(word)
           else:
               mydict[firstletter] = [word]
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['ability', 'absolute'], 'b': ['butterfly'], 'c': ['cloud']}
```

Also (not related to the question) it's better to use the `with` statement to open your file, that will also close it once you're done working with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way

```
mydict = {}
a = ['apple', 'abc', 'b', 'c']
for word in a:
    word = word.strip().lower() #makes the word lower case and strips any unexpected chars
    firstletter = word[0]
    if firstletter in mydict.keys():
        values = mydict[firstletter] # Get the origial values/words 
        values.append(word) # Append new word to the list of words
        mydict[firstletter] = values
    else:
        mydict[firstletter] = [word]

print(mydict)
```

Outout :

```
{'a': ['apple', 'abc'], 'c': ['c'], 'b': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

mydict[firstletter] = [word], replaces the value

Since the key are in List format, try

```
mydict[firstletter].extend(word)
```

Comment: Output = {'a': ['ability', 'a', 'b', 's', 'o', 'l', 'u', 't', 'e'], 'b': ['butterfly'], 'c': ['cloud']}.

Comment: If you want to use `extend` you should pass a list to it, like `.extend([word])`.

Comment: I think it becoz if the .strip() in a for loop is causing that Output, I tried the other answers here and I got the same issue too

Comment: @AvichalBettoli no, it's not, I tried your code and I got the same result, but if you replace `extend(word)` with `extend([word])` it works fine.